# A tree with a lexicographic order is a linear ordered structure

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, trees, lattice-orders, reverse-math

Let T be a binary tree. In RCA0, I wanted to show that (T,<) is a linear ordered structure where < means the lexicographic ordering on T.
I tried to prove it, and I did. I think my proof works; but it became too long. It is a little part of my dissertation project, and I don't want to write about it too much. So I decided to use a reference.

could you please introduce me some textbook, paper, etc which in that, it somehow claims that (T,<) is a linear ordered structure? This will do, but Better If it has proved it.

Comment: Should this have [reference-request] tag?

Comment: @C7X Sorry I don't know. Please if you have a resource in mind, write its name, I'll goggle it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a reference in mind myself.